# WPF ListView grows bigger than it's containing Canvas

Tags: wpf, listview, datatable, size

I have a `ListView` which is using a `GridView` to display a `DataTable` and when new rows are added to the `DataTable` the `ListView` grows as expected but when it reaches the bottom of the `Canvas` it carries on growing.

I want it to stop when it reaches the height of the `Canvas`, how can I configure this?

The `Canvas` has a dynamic height which is controlled by the `DockPanel` it is contained in.

```
<Canvas>
    <ListView Name="listResults" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Request Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RequestTime}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Request Duration(ms)" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Duration}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Request Duration(ms)" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Duration}" />
            </GridView>                            
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `MaxHeight` property on your `ListView`.  You could hard code it, or you could bind it to the `ActualHeight` property of the `Canvas`.

Comment: @muaddib Actually, Binding 'MaxHeight' with parent control 'ActualHeight' works very well with Canvas, but not with DockPanel. Any suggestions using DockPanel as a parent?

Comment: Just checked, it is not a problem with DockPanel, but something else, I cannot paste a short code with not-working example, unfortunately.